# Oscillation Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

[image]

Now normally (if it was a block not rotating) all you would have to do is use $w^2 = k/m$ and $E= \frac12k(A\cos(2wt+\theta))^2 + \frac12m(Aw\sin(wt+\theta))^2$ or in other words the translational kinetic and spring potential.

But here I don't even know how to start.

Please could someone set up what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use energy conservation still. The total energy of the system is still $\frac{1}{2}kd^2$. The difference here is that you will have an extra term in your kinetic energy due to the rotation.